# Can we select multiple files in single attempt using UIDocumentMenuViewController if yes then how?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my current project I am using UIDocumentMenuViewController and its working perfectly fine with single file selection.

Now I want to allow user to select multiple file at a time. let say 10 file max in single attempt. I have tried to find out may URLs but did not get any solution.

Please provide solution on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use UIDocumentPickerViewController for select multiple files

Comment: I have tried using UIDocumentPickerViewController but when I select single file its delegate method get called and meanwhile its already dismissed. So not able to select multiple files at a time.

Answer (score 1):

**According to documentation**

**1).** A document interaction controller, along with a delegate object, provides in-app support for managing user interactions with files in the local system.

**2).** For example, an email program might use this class to allow the user to preview attachments and open them in other apps.

**3).** Use this class to present an appropriate user interface for previewing, opening, copying, or printing a specified file.

**4).** So only one file can be shared among two apps using UIDocumentInteractionController.